# Custom UITableViewCell Indentation Issue

Tags: ios, uitableview

I've got an interesting problem (please forgive me if this was asked... I searched Google, actually Bing since I don't use Google, and stack with no results).

I am creating a custom UITableViewCell with UIIMageView (310 x 310) inside of the content view of the cell. When everything is said and done and I actually set the image of the imageView in my controller using cellForRow:

`[feedCell.imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image-placeholder"]];`

I get this result:

[image: Not what I want.]

^ Not what I want.

When I get the image view from the tableView using viewWithTag method and then set the image of the imageView directly, I get the desired result:

```
UIImageView *imageView = (UIImageView *)[tableView viewWithTag:1];
[imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image-placeholder"]];
```

[image]

So the question is, what is it that I am missing? Why would setting the imageView via custom cell class be so off while it works otherwise? I would love to use custom subclass.

P.S. Don't mind Batman stuff. Although I am kind of a fan... liked the 2nd one the best.

Comment: not sure but it happened because cell.imageView size is 40x40 and you put image like 310x310.. so..

Comment: if you display image different cell then you set cell height correctly.

Comment: make sure it is not due to auto layout

Comment: @iPatel It's a custom cell.

Comment: @nitinkachhadiya my custom cell height is 360 points. Image view is 310 x 310.

Comment: @umersufyan auto layout is off.

Answer (score 0):

Check the code below

```
UIImageView *imageView = (UIImageView *)[tableView viewWithTag:1];
[imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image-placeholder"]];

//Put the code below
[imageView setClipsToBounds:YES];
```

and,

```
[feedCell.imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image-placeholder"]];
[feedCell.imageView setClipsToBounds:YES];
```

Comment: Unfortunately [feedCell.imageView setClipsToBounds:YES]; didn't help. I feel like I am missing something insignificant here.

Comment: Just to make it clearer: 

UIImageView *imageView = (UIImageView *)[tableView viewWithTag:1];
[imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image-placeholder"]]; 

Works just fine.

Comment: Its the issue with setting the image using custom cell class.